# Full stack templating?

Tags: scala, backbone.js, frameworks, coffeescript, marionette

Reusability and abstraction is killing me; I've clearly been doing a lot of client-side development. CoffeeScript, Backbone, and Marionette have helped. Still, building completely reusable, modular "templates" - from the server-side and up - has not been possible. Let me describe a problem from the top down, and then maybe you can help describe the best stack.

I want to build a login widget that can be versioned and reused across multiple applications using the same framework (this is a basic whimsical example, take it with a few grains of salt). One large application is a bad idea, and they're hosted separately anyways. All the separate applications use the same API, hosted elsewhere, and no JSONP is acceptable.

**Client-side**

A login form would be comprised of a Marionette ItemView, some jQuery functions to handle all the fancy-dancy interaction, a Backbone "Account" model which handles various aspects of POST, GET, DELETE, and some basic html with the View is bound to. **Normally, I'd have to explicity set the urlRoot for the AJAX interaction (see below), but I'd just like to be able to say '/' + @attributes.email, as it wouldn't matter what the ROUTE was, as everything is bundled together.**

```
class Account extends Backbone.Model  
  # Normal
  create: () ->
    @urlRoot = () ->
      '/account/' + @attributes.email
    @save()

  # Ideal
  create: () ->
    @urlRoot = () ->
      '/' + @attributes.email
    @save()
```

**Server-side**

This is built in accordance with the client-side (hopefully in Scala), and instead of explicitly defining a ROUTE somewhere:

```
POST /account/:email controllers.Account.create(password: String) # Play 2.0 syntax
```

I'd simply be able to say:

```
@POST(/:email?password=[String]) # Made up syntax
create(email, password) = {
  
  # Hit external API 
  val json = WS.url('https://someapi/v1/account').withQueryParams('email=' + email + '&password=' + password).get()

  # Return some response
  Ok(json)

}
```

The application framework would know this module, or template, as `@account()` perhaps, and If I wanted to build a home page with login capability, I'd simply do something like:

```
<html>
  Oh hey cool stuffz, sign up or login please
  <right column>
    @account()
  <end right column>
  @social() <!-- perhaps another template -->
<html>
```

What I envision is the application layer abstracting the client-to-server calls from the modules into GUIDs, perhaps, so making that `create account' call would really be doing something like:

```
POST /35395235/:email account.create(password: String)
```

While I understand this doesn't necessarily exist, I've stumbled upon Lift, and it seems relatively promising, but still not quite abstracted as I had hoped. Thoughts?

Comment: http://dropwizard.codahale.com/ seems interesting.

Comment: From my experience on a Corporate world, what you are describing here is a Single sign-on implementation more than just a "login widget". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on